# ORACLE SQL: Include null values with count

Tags: oracle, select, null, oracle-sqldeveloper

When using the following (part of a) query, I'm getting the following result:

```
SELECT TLC, DUTYTYPE, SUM(SUM1)  FROM
**Result**

Person1 Category1   4
Person1 Category3   5
Person1 Category4   7
Person2 Category1   8
Person2 Category2   2
Person2 Category3   1
Person2 Category4   3
Person3 Category2   9
Person3 Category4   3
```

I want it to look like this:

```
Person  Category    Count
Person1 Category1   4
Person1 Category2   0
Person1 Category3   5
Person1 Category4   7
Person2 Category1   8
Person2 Category2   2
Person2 Category3   1
Person2 Category4   3
Person3 Category1   0
Person3 Category2   9
Person3 Category3   0
Person3 Category4   3
```

So if a sum/count results in NULL is it still included. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Is there a `GROUP BY` somewhere in your query which you omitted here?  If the missing data isn't represented in the original table, then you'll have to do something like use a calendar table (or analog) to fill in the holes.

Comment: Where do you have a complete list of person and categories?  You have to start w/ that table and outer join to the one containing what you want to count otherwise you don't have the data to count.  Like if we had a customer and sales table.  we can count all the sales in in the sales table by customer, but if a customer has no sales, they wouldn't show up.. you'd have to join to the customer and then the count of 0 would show up.

Comment: A complete query (even if simplified ) would be a better example. However it sounds like you want to do an OUTER JOIN between the table that has the rows that you are performing the SUM against.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Thanks to this, I eventually created four new columns for every category and I summed these values grouped by person. By using unpivot I got the result I wanted. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a NVL to pick up the null values. If this is what you are wanting.

```
SELECT TLC, DUTYTYPE, NVL(SUM(SUM1), 0)  FROM
**Result**
```

You may need an OUTER JOIN.  Also take into consideration possible NOT NULL attributes.  Do you have your entire code?